# Possible to use $1 within Bash array?

Tags: arrays, bash

The script I'm writing will require me to pass some command line parameters. I would like to use these parameters within an array, but I'm not sure how.

A very basic example of this would be (script run as `./script.sh array1`):

```
#!/bin/bash
array1=( a b c d )

echo ${#$1[@]}
```

The output should be 4, but I receive the following error:
`line 5: ${#$1[@]}: bad substitution`.

I don't *have* to use arrays, but would like to.

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get bash to substitute the value of $1 before evaluating the line, try this...

```
eval echo \${#$1[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval echo '${#'$1'[@]};'
```